# Some help needed with guard expression in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to write a guard expression for my function which will not accept char lists, so I do this:

```rb
def myfunction(path) when is_list(path) do
```

the problem here is that `is_list` also returns true when a character list such as 'path' is given, how would I go about this?

Comment: But a character list is a list, so you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `is_binary`. Will return `true` for Strings, `false` for Lists in the way you define it.

Comment: Almost....   ```iex(7)> is_list('hello') and not is_binary('hello')
true
iex(8)> is_list("hello") and not is_binary("hello")
false
iex(9)> is_list(["hello"]) and not is_binary(["hello"])
true
```

Comment: @LowKianSeong you can't check for iodata in a guard. `is_list([...])` will always return `true` regardless of the list contents. `is_binary(...)` returns `true` only for binaries.